# Facebook action does not specify any reference objects using android while publishing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

My action is 'find'. Object is : 'valentine' . But in the property field my object's name is 'valentine_' of type 'Reference' .

Now, I am trying publish 'find' action using ANDROID which gives error message : 
"The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified : valentine_"

My Code :

```
private interface ValentineGraphObject extends GraphObject{
        public String getUrl();
        public void setUrl(String url);

         public String getId();
        public void setId(String id);
    }





    private interface FindAction extends OpenGraphAction{
        // The valentine object 
        public ValentineGraphObject getValentine();
        public void setValentine(ValentineGraphObject valentine_);
    }





    protected void populateOGAction(OpenGraphAction action) {
        FindAction findaction = action.cast(FindAction.class);
        ValentineGraphObject valentine_ =GraphObject.Factory.create(ValentineGraphObject.class);
        valentine_.setUrl("http://milliondollarsapps.com/Kunal/valen.html");
        findaction.setValentine(valentine_);
    }
```

Can some help me on this.
Quick help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does no one knows the answer of this question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you have a mismatch between the property on your FindAction interface (which is setValentine, and gets translated to just "valentine"), and the property in your OG action (which is "valentine_").

There are two ways to solve this:

a. Instead of using findaction.setValentine(...) do:

```
findaction.setProperty("valentine_", valentine_);
```

b. Use the PropertyName annotation on your setValentine method:

```
private interface FindAction extends OpenGraphAction{
    // The valentine object 
    public ValentineGraphObject getValentine();
    @PropertyName("valentine_")
    public void setValentine(ValentineGraphObject valentine_);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ming Li for your response. I tried 2nd approach, but it is still showing the same error. For the 1st approach, I got Facebookgraphobjectaction. I set : findaction.setProperty(String s,ValentineGraphObject valentine_);

Comment: Kindly provide your inputs on this. Thanks

Comment: For 1st one I got : FacebookgraphobjectactionException: Factory can't proxy method findaction.setProperty(String s,ValentineGraphObject valentine_);

Comment: 2nd approach worked when I tried again... Thank you very much Ming Li :)